# How to work with Sockets in swift?

Tags: swift3, socket.io, latitude-longitude

I have used this https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift for socket integration. I want to send 4 parameters for example location updates latitude, longitude, ID and Sequence to server.

In this scenario how can I use sockets?

Comment: You should follow the steps to initialize socket first of all. After that you can use `socket.emit` method to send data to server.

Comment: @ridvankucuk. Thank u. please guide me i have added url also parameters like this first             let socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: URL(string: "http://"+SERV_HOST_PORT+"/gs-guide-websocket?access_token=\(accessToken!)")!, config:[.connectParams(parameters)])

Comment: If you set it to a variable then ; `self.socket.emit("message", "YOUR CONTENT HERE" )` this one should work

Comment: @ridvankucuk. I want to send 4 parameters so self.socker.emit("/api/url",[parametres]) is this correct format

Comment: You can send array with emit method. It should just support SocketData protocol. You can access the supported types in SocketTypes.swift class.

Comment: @ridvankucuk. when i send like that i am getting error like full authentication required to access this url.

Comment: I suppose that you have already implemented an authentication on the server side. On the client side before emiting a custom message, you should emit an authentication packet.